# How can I fix this memory issue in my maximum matching algorithm with RealmSwift?

Tags: algorithm, swift, realm, text-segmentation

I wrote my own maximum matching function in Swift to divide Chinese sentences into words. It works fine, except with abnormally long sentences the memory usage goes up over 1 gb. I need help figuring out how to modify my code so that there isn't this memory problem. I'm not sure if it has to do with how I am using RealmSwift or if it is my algorithm in general.

Here is my code:

```
    func splitSentenceIntoWordsWithDictionaryMaximumMatching(string: String) -> [String] {
    var string = string
    var foundWordsArray: [String] = []
    var position = count(string)

    while position > 0
    {
        var index = advance(string.startIndex, position)
        let partialString = string.substringToIndex(index)
        if let found = Realm().objects(Word).filter("simplified == '\(partialString)'").first
        {
            foundWordsArray.append(partialString)
            position = position - 1
            var partialStringCount = count(partialString)
            while partialStringCount > 0
            {
                string = dropFirst(string)
                partialStringCount -= 1
            }
            position = count(string)
            index = advance(string.startIndex, position)
        }
        else if count(partialString) == 1
        {
            addNewEntryToDictionaryInTransaction(partialString, "", [partialString], partialString)
            foundWordsArray.append(partialString)
            var partialStringCount = count(partialString)
            while partialStringCount > 0
            {
                string = dropFirst(string)
                partialStringCount -= 1
            }
            position = count(string)
            index = advance(string.startIndex, position)
        }
        else
        {
            position = position - 1
            index = advance(string.startIndex, position)
        }
    }

    return foundWordsArray
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should use `autoreleasepool` (see:  [Use Local Autorelease Pool Blocks to Reduce Peak Memory Footprint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW2)) in the loop:

```
    while position > 0 {
        autoreleasepool {
            var index = advance(string.startIndex, position)
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

BTW, your code has too many memory copy operations and `O(N)` operations on `String.Index` (`count()` and `advance()`), that may cause serious performance problems. Instead, you should effectively use `String.Index` something like this :

```
import Foundation

var  words:Set = ["今日", "献立", "魚", "味噌汁", "定食", "焼き魚", "です"]
func splitSentenceIntoWordsWithDictionaryMaximumMatching(string: String) -> [String] {
    var foundWordsArray: [String] = []
    var start = string.startIndex
    var end = string.endIndex

    while start != end {
        autoreleasepool { // In this case(using builtin `Set`), I think we don't need `autoreleasepool` here. But this is just a demo :)
            let partialString = string[start ..< end]
            if !words.contains(partialString) {
                if end.predecessor() != start { // faster way of `count(partialString) == 1`
                    end = end.predecessor()
                    return // we cannot use `continue` here because we are in `autoreleasepool` closure
                }
                words.insert(partialString)
            }
            foundWordsArray.append(partialString)
            start = end
            end = string.endIndex
        }
    }

    return foundWordsArray
}

var str = "今日の献立は焼き魚定食と味噌汁です"
let result = splitSentenceIntoWordsWithDictionaryMaximumMatching(str)

debugPrintln(result) // ["今日", "の", "献立", "は", "焼き魚", "定食", "と", "味噌汁", "です"]
debugPrintln(words) // Set(["献立", "焼き魚", "今日", "魚", "味噌汁", "定食", "は", "と", "です", "の"])
```

I used builtin `Set`, but I think you can easily adopts your `Realm` codes here :)

---

ADDED: in reply to the comments:

reversed version:

```
var  words:Set = ["研究", "研究生", "生命", "起源"]
func splitSentenceIntoWordsWithDictionaryMaximumMatchingReversed(string: String) -> [String] {
    var foundWordsArray: [String] = []
    var start = string.startIndex
    var end = string.endIndex

    while start != end {
        autoreleasepool {
            let partialString = string[start ..< end]
            if !words.contains(partialString) {
                if start.successor() != end {
                    start = start.successor()
                    return
                }
                words.insert(partialString)
            }
            foundWordsArray.append(partialString)
            end = start
            start = string.startIndex
        }
    }

    return foundWordsArray.reverse()
}

var str = "研究生命起源"
let result = splitSentenceIntoWordsWithDictionaryMaximumMatchingReversed(str)

debugPrintln(result) // ["研究", "生命", "起源"]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. With the Realm code you still need the autoreleasepool.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how to do this in reverse? In addition to the way this function does it, I need another function that matches from the back of the string instead of from the front. The part I am having most trouble with is ```let partialString = string[start ..< end]```. Should it be something like ```let partialString = string[end ..< start]```? (of course that doesn't work)` ```fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start
```

Comment: I can award you a bounty if you help me do the same thing in reverse.

Comment: I'm not sure what "reverse" you mean. When you have words `"ABC", "CDE", "EDC", "CBA"` and a string `"ABCDE"`, what you expect as a result? BTW, I don't need bounty or reps for this :)

Comment: I mean if the text is "研究生命起源" then forward would return "["研究生","命","起源"] because "研究生" is the longest word in the front. Reverse would return ["研究","生命","起源"]. because it would start from the end and find "生命" before it finally finds "研究".

Comment: Both functions would be returning valid results because both "研究生" and "研究" are in the dictionary as well as both "生命" and "命".

Comment: Thank you. Bounty in 23 hours.